# How to tag IPv4 and IPv6 packets with different VLAN tags on a Linux box?

Tags: debian, ipv6, vlan, ipv4, systemd-networkd

I want to tag incoming IPv4 and IPv6 packets from a dual stack enabled connection with different VLAN tags, e.g. IPv4 packets should go to VLAN4 and IPv6 packets should go to VLAN6. To be more general, I want to split the dual stack ip stream with mixed IPv4 and IPv6 packets into two clean single stack networks so you will not find any IPv4 packet on a IPv6 network and vise versa. I need this to test and support an IPv6 only network. And of course I still need the IPv4 data. It cannot simply be dropped.

```
                          Linux Box
                       Debian Bullseye
       untagged         ┏━━━━━━━━━━━┓         tagged (trunk)
════════════════════════┫eth0  vlan4┣═╦══════════════════════
     IPv4 and IPv6      ┃      vlan6┣═╝eth1  IPv4 with VLAN4 tag
      dual stack        ┗━━━━━━━━━━━┛        IPv6 with VLAN6 tag
```

I had a look at the Linux bridge and at `nftables` but wasn't able to find a solution. How can I achieve this selective tagging?

Comment: Show your VLAN interfaces and routing table.

Comment: Is the Linux box acting as a router, or a bridge?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Thanks for having a look at the question and asking for details. Only looking for an example to answer the details give me the idea for a solution :-)

Comment: @GordonDavisson It is not the question what we have. The goal defines what to use. In this case we have to use a bridge as I found in my answer.

Comment: Is there a reason you cannot simply have the two vlan interfaces and assign the local addresses to these to match what you like, letting the normal routing table do the work instead of all this bridging and filtering and stuff?

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist What addresses do you mean? Do you mean simple routing on layer 3? How would you tag the packets? There are no different networks. Only packets shall get a VLAN tag. If it is possible what you have in mind, it would be great if you could create an answer.

Comment: @Ingo Whether it's possible or not depends on whether your answer to Gordon was accurate. Ie, if you truly could have done routing instead of bridging, then it would have been a simple matter of just routing the v4 and v6 IP networks to the different vlan interfaces (the whole purpose of the OS-level abstraction of having interfaces for the vlans is to let it deal with the tags). I don't know what you mean by "there are no different networks", though.

Comment: @Ingo Point being, you are not being very clear about what the goal actually is, but you responded to that comment that the goal implies doing bridging. If the goal truly implies bridging is necessary, then it is not possible to do routing instead.... but I have no way of knowing as you never clarified the goal.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist The goal is noted in the very first sentence. Do you mean it could be a X-Y problem? I have added a more general description to the question. You wrote: '*I don't know what you mean by "there are no different networks"* ' - Layer 3 routing as performed by network router is done by routing network traffic between different (maybe virtual) interfaces, each interface sitting on a different network (subnet), e.g. 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24. A device with one interface cannot be a router.

Comment: @HåkanLindqvist On Linux you have to explicitly enable routing with setting `ip_forward` on the virtual `/proc` filesystem. But I have a mixed IPv4/IPv6 datastream on one network. There is no second network/subnet. That is what I mean. But anyway, this meta discussion does not take us one step forward to a simpler solution. I will have a look again to a Layer 3 routing solution. Do you have an idea to get an IPv6 only network without loosing IPv4 data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a solution. Because I want to manipulate VLANs, I have to use a bridge. VLAN is working on OSI layer 2 and a bridge is the device that can handle layer 2 protocols. So first I added two VLAN interfaces to the physical interface **eth1**. Then added all interfaces **eth0**, **vlan4** and **vlan6** to the bridge. The rest is done by **nftables**.

IPv4 and IPv6 are defined on layer3 and have no different meaning on layer 2. So *nftables* can handle them just as packets with different "marks", which is the protocol type in the IP header. Fortunately *nftables* can select them with `meta protocol {}`. It directs the incoming untagged IPv4 and IPv6 packets to the corresponding VLAN interface. Tagging is done automagically by the interface as usual. I use **systemd-networkd** and here is the configuration in detail.

First create the network devices vlan4, vlan6 and the bridge br0:

```
~$ sudo -Es
~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/01-vlan4.netdev <<EOF
[NetDev]
Name=vlan4
Kind=vlan
[VLAN]
Id=4
EOF

~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/02-vlan6.netdev <<EOF
[NetDev]
Name=vlan6
Kind=vlan
[VLAN]
Id=6
EOF

~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/03-br0.netdev <<EOF
[NetDev]
Name=br0
Kind=bridge
[Bridge]
DefaultPVID=6
VLANProtocol=802.1q
STP=no
EOF
```

Then attach the interfaces to eth1 and to the bridge:

```
~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/12-eth1_attach-vlans.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=eth1
[Network]
LLMNR=no
LinkLocalAddressing=no
VLAN=vlan4
VLAN=vlan6
EOF

~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/16-ifs_add_to_br0.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=eth0 vlan4 vlan6
[Network]
Bridge=br0
LLMNR=no
LinkLocalAddressing=no
EOF
```

Now just bring up the bridge:

```
~# cat > /etc/systemd/network/20-br0-up.network <<EOF
[Match]
Name=br0
[Network]
LLMNR=no
MulticastDNS=yes
EOF
```

After a reboot this will give you:

```
~$ ip -brief address
lo               UNKNOWN        127.0.0.1/8 ::1/128
eth0             UP
br0              UP             2003:d5:2721:900:9012:fdff:fef0:ea7f/64 fe80::9012:fdff:fef0:ea7f/64
vlan6@eth1       UP
vlan4@eth1       UP
eth1             UP

# these are the slave interfaces of the bridge
~$ sudo bridge link show
4: vlan6@eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 4
5: vlan4@eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 4
6: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 master br0 state forwarding priority 32 cost 4
```

It is also worth to check with `resolvectl`. Now we have to do the final step and redirect the packets with **nftables** using these rules:

```
~$ cat /etc/nftables.conf
#!/usr/sbin/nft -f

flush ruleset

table bridge filter {
    chain forward {
        type filter hook forward priority 0; policy accept;
        meta protocol { ip6 } iifname "vlan4" drop
        meta protocol { ip6 } oifname "vlan4" drop
        meta protocol { ip6 } iifname "vlan6" accept
        meta protocol { ip6 } oifname "vlan6" accept
        iifname "vlan6" drop
        oifname "vlan6" drop
    }

    chain output {
        type filter hook output priority 0; policy drop;
        meta protocol { ip6 } iifname "vlan6" accept
        meta protocol { ip6 } oifname "vlan6" accept
    }
}
```

On the forward chain this will drop all IPv6 to/from interface *vlan4* and only allow it on interface *vlan6*. All other stuff is dropped on interface *vlan6*, but by the chains default policy accepted on interface *vlan4*. This ensures that all old stuff like ARP and other broadcasts go also to interface *vlan4*.

The output chain is only to avoid that the bridge itself sends packets to the wrong VLAN. On my configuration it uses only IPv6 (single stack) so everything will be dropped by the chains default policy, except IPv6 to *vlan6*.

Answer (score 3):

While your answer apparantly works for you, it does seem overly complicated. I'm doubtful though that it does what you want, as it lacks any IPv4 addresses in the given output (apart from lo).

Creating 2 tagged interfaces (named e.g. vlan4 and vlan6), assigning them IPv4 and IPv6 addresses + gateways, and disabling SLAAC with sysctl for the IPv4 one should be sufficient.

There's neither need for bridging nor messing with nftables apart from what you would need to enable flow between eth0 and eth1.

Comment: This does not answer my question. You suggest to split one line into two interfaces. As shown in the drawing I have only one line to continue and it must be a so called trunk line for upstream connection to a router. A trunked line is one line transporting several virtual networks where the ip packets are differentiated by the VLAN tag.